# Why Inno Setup skips installing executable file on some machines?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I am having an Inno Setup to package an application. While trying to install the application, it works like a charm except for in one Windows 10 machine where the setup does not copy the main executable file (`#MyAppExeName`).

I am not sure of the reason. Because in all other machines it works perfectly.

So in this particular machine when I navigate to the installation location, the main executable file is missing. So Windows shows a popup saying:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

[image]

Do you have any idea why Inno Setup fails to copy the main executable file in one particular machine?

Down below, you will find the snippet of Inno Setup script I use:
Note: `inputfile` and `inputfolder` are passed during compilation.

```
#define MyAppExeName "World Tool.exe"

[Files]
Source: "{#inputfile}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#inputfolder}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Installer log:

```
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+01:00)
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.9 (u)
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   Original Setup EXE: C:\tool TEST\World Tool Setup_1.0.162.exe
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   Setup command line: /SL5="$50898,6602287,143872,C:\tool TEST\World Tool Setup_1.0.162.exe" /SPAWNWND=$B08A4 /NOTIFYWND=$150848 /LOG="C:\Users\username\Desktop\setup_log.txt"
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   Windows version: 10.0.10586  (NT platform: Yes)
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   64-bit Windows: Yes
2019-01-09 11:57:01.092   Processor architecture: x64
2019-01-09 11:57:01.093   User privileges: Administrative
2019-01-09 11:57:01.094   64-bit install mode: No
2019-01-09 11:57:02.108   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\itadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-QMU4N.tmp
2019-01-09 11:57:08.478   Starting the installation process.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.482   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\World
2019-01-09 11:57:08.482   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool
2019-01-09 11:57:08.483   Creating directory: C:\ProgramData\World
2019-01-09 11:57:08.483   Creating directory: C:\ProgramData\World\Global World Tool
2019-01-09 11:57:08.483   Creating directory: C:\ProgramData\World\Global World Tool\data
2019-01-09 11:57:08.483   Setting permissions on directory: C:\ProgramData\World\Global World Tool\data
2019-01-09 11:57:08.485   Creating directory: C:\ProgramData\World\Global World Tool\log
2019-01-09 11:57:08.485   Setting permissions on directory: C:\ProgramData\World\Global World Tool\log
2019-01-09 11:57:08.486   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool
2019-01-09 11:57:08.486   Creating new uninstall log: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\unins000.dat
2019-01-09 11:57:08.488   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.489   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\unins000.exe
2019-01-09 11:57:08.491   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 11:57:01.020
2019-01-09 11:57:08.491   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.493   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2019-01-09 11:57:08.494   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.495   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.495   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\config.ini
2019-01-09 11:57:08.495   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:10.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.495   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.497   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.497   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.498   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\ControlzEx.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.498   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-14 20:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.498   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.510   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.510   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.510   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\ControlzEx.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:08.510   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-14 20:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.510   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.521   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.521   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.521   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\DatasetReadWrite.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.521   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.522   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.526   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.526   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.527   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\gstStatic.db3
2019-01-09 11:57:08.527   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:10.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.527   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.528   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.528   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.529   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\MahApps.Metro.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.529   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.529   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.574   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.574   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.575   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\MahApps.Metro.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:08.575   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-13 15:18:56.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.575   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.607   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.608   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.608   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\MqttBroker.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.609   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:12.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.609   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.613   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.613   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.613   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.613   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-24 17:44:14.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.613   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.641   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.641   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.641   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\NTL.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.641   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.641   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.666   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.666   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.666   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.666   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.666   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.670   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.670   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.671   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:08.671   Time stamp of our file: 2018-01-31 12:06:12.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.671   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.672   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.672   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.672   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Plugin.Connectivity.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.672   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.672   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.675   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.675   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.675   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Plugin.Connectivity.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:08.675   Time stamp of our file: 2018-01-31 12:06:12.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.675   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.677   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.677   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.677   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Portable.Text.Encoding.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.677   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.677   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.734   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.734   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.734   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\ProgramAgentLib.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:08.735   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.735   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.989   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.989   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.989   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe.config
2019-01-09 11:57:08.990   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:38.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.990   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.991   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.991   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.992   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:08.992   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:42.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.992   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.000   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.000   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.001   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\WorldApp.Core.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.001   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.001   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.035   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.035   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.035   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\WorldApp.Core.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:09.035   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:30.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.035   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.056   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.056   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.057   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\ServiceBoxLib.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.057   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.057   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.062   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.062   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.062   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\SQLite-net.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.063   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.063   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.070   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.070   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.070   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\SQLite-net.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:09.070   Time stamp of our file: 2017-07-27 16:44:06.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.070   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.072   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.072   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.073   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.073   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.073   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.075   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.075   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.075   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.076   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.076   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.085   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.085   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.085   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.086   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.086   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.090   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.090   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.090   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.090   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.090   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.094   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.094   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.094   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.AppContext.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.095   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:07:16.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.095   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.097   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.097   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.097   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Collections.Immutable.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.098   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:07:18.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.098   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.107   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.107   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.108   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.108   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:07:58.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.108   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.109   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.109   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.110   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.110   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:08:00.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.110   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.112   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.112   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.112   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.113   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:08:06.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.113   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.114   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.114   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.115   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.IO.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.115   Time stamp of our file: 2016-11-05 04:56:18.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.115   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.117   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.117   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.117   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.IO.FileSystem.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.118   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:08:12.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.118   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.119   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.120   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.120   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.120   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:08:14.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.120   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.121   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.122   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.122   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.122   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:08:26.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.122   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.123   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.124   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.124   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.124   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:09:04.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.124   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.128   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.128   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.128   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.129   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:09:18.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.129   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.132   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.132   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.132   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.132   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:09:30.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.132   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.144   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.144   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.144   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.144   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:09:36.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.144   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.146   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.146   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.147   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Runtime.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.147   Time stamp of our file: 2016-11-05 04:57:10.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.147   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.149   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.150   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.151   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.151   Time stamp of our file: 2016-11-05 04:56:50.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.151   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.153   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.153   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.154   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Security.Claims.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.154   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:10:10.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.154   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.155   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.156   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.156   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.156   Time stamp of our file: 2015-07-22 23:10:58.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.156   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.165   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.165   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.165   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.166   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.166   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.170   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.170   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.170   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Unosquare.Labs.EmbedIO.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.171   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-07 16:11:50.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.171   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.181   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.181   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.182   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Unosquare.Swan.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.182   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-13 18:24:58.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.182   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.192   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.192   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.192   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Unosquare.Swan.Lite.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.192   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-12 17:34:42.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.192   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.200   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.200   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.201   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\WorldCommunication.Common.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.201   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.201   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.205   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.205   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.205   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.205   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.205   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.245   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.245   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.245   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Xamarin.Forms.Core.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:09.246   Time stamp of our file: 2017-11-15 18:16:08.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.246   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.289   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.289   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.289   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.290   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.290   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.299   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.299   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.300   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.300   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.300   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.307   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.307   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.307   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.pdb
2019-01-09 11:57:09.308   Time stamp of our file: 2017-11-15 18:16:08.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.308   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.314   Successfully installed the file.
... (some file skipped)
2019-01-09 11:57:09.386   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.386   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\x64\e_sqlite3.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.386   Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-01 13:27:42.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.386   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.386   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\x64
2019-01-09 11:57:09.442   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.442   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.443   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\x86\e_sqlite3.dll
2019-01-09 11:57:09.443   Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-01 13:27:42.000
2019-01-09 11:57:09.443   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.443   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\x86
2019-01-09 11:57:09.489   Successfully installed the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.489   -- Icon entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.489   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\World Tool.lnk
2019-01-09 11:57:09.490   Creating the icon.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.526   Successfully created the icon.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.533   -- Icon entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:09.533   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\Desktop\World Tool.lnk
2019-01-09 11:57:09.533   Creating the icon.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.535   Successfully created the icon.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.549   Installation process succeeded.
2019-01-09 11:57:09.552   Need to restart Windows? No
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   -- Run entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   Run as: Original user
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   Type: Exec
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe
2019-01-09 11:57:10.465   Exception message:
2019-01-09 11:57:10.465   Message box (OK):
                          Unable to execute file:
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe

                          CreateProcess failed; code 5.
                          Access is denied.
2019-01-09 11:57:11.678   User chose OK.
2019-01-09 11:57:12.683   Deinitializing Setup.
2019-01-09 11:57:12.691   Log closed.
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl added log file.

Comment: My bad, the main executable file name is World Tool.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log file, the `C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe` file is clearly installed without any problem:

```
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   -- File entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-09 10:32:52.000
2019-01-09 11:57:08.739   Installing the file.
2019-01-09 11:57:08.989   Successfully installed the file.
```

If it does not exist after installation finishes, you will need to look elsewhere. I'd check if it was not deleted by an antivirus (or similar) application.

Also note that when the installer tries to run the application, it does not fail with *"file not exists"*, but with *"access is denied"* - what indicates that the file existed at that moment - but maybe it was locked by an antivirus scan or prevent from being run (and subsequently deleted).

```
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   -- Run entry --
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   Run as: Original user
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   Type: Exec
2019-01-09 11:57:10.432   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe
2019-01-09 11:57:10.465   Exception message:
2019-01-09 11:57:10.465   Message box (OK):
                          Unable to execute file:
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\World\World Tool\World Tool.exe

                          CreateProcess failed; code 5.
                          Access is denied.
```

Comment: You were right. The antivirus application has quarantined the main executable file. Thank you.